changing order of union and cartesian product
Let $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$, $B_4$ be any sets then we know that we can say
$(B_1 \bigcup B_2) \times (B_3 \bigcup B_4) = (B_1 \times B_3) \bigcup (B_1 \times B_4) \bigcup (B_2 \times B_3) \bigcup (B_2 \times B_4) $
but I want to generalise this result for $\prod_{i\in I} \bigcup_{j\in J_i} B_{(i,j)}$, i.e. I want to bring the union operation to the left, but I dont know how would I write that expression in a compact form if $I$ and $J_i$ are arbitrary index sets (may be uncountable). Neither am I able to prove that such a change of order of product and union will always exist. In case it is not true, I am also not able to find any counter example for this. Please help.

I think you are looking for the following formula:
$$
\prod_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J_i} B_{ij} = \bigcup_{j \in \prod_{i \in I} J_i} \prod_{i \in I} B_{i,j_i}
$$
Does the proper formulation help you in writing down a proof?

you have used $j_i$ in the subscript of B in RHS but under the union symbol, you have just written j, so what does that mean? Also kindly note that you are doing an arbitrary product of $J_i$ under the union symbol but since I may be uncountable set, the arbitrary product may be represented as a set of functions, so I am not sure whether that would be make sense or not.

Its basically another notation for $j(i)$.
